# Residual autocorrelation in non-stationary (gaulss) model

Tags: r, stationarity, spatial, gamlss, variogram

I'm fitting a non-stationary model using `mgcv` (family: `gaulss()`) where the data have been collected at different points in space. The dataset is large (N>10000) and was collected at essentially equal distances from each other across the spatial domain. Here's a simplified version of what the model looks like in `R`:

```
f <- y ~ s(x) #Mean model
f2 <- ~ s(x) #Variance model
flist <- list(f, f2) #List of model formulae
mod <- gam(flist, family=gaulss(), data=dat) #Fit location-scale (non-stationary) model
```

Simple residual diagnostics (Q-Q plots) appear OK, but since the data were collected over space, I'd like to look at spatial autocorrelation in the residuals. Using the `variogram` function from the `gstat` library, I've made variograms of two types of residuals: response residuals ($y - \hat{y}$) and "deviance" residuals ($\frac{y-\hat{y}}{\sigma}$). As you can see, the results are very different:

[image]

My question is: **which type of residual is appropriate for assessing spatial (or temporal) autocorrelation in non-stationary models?**